# (array formula?) Excel to return the next date of a stock price rebounding

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, vlookup

[image: excel print screen]

Dear Excel Gurus,

Goal: I have some historical stock prices handy, but have trouble looking up when and if the price eventually rebounds.

Logic elaboration:
Please click on above link to open a screen cap, as a picture beats a thousand words.

At Jan5th closing (cell E3), the index rose by 456 points from Jan4th 's 21823 (cell E2).
Price eventually touches this level again on Jan13th (because day low in cell C13 breaches 21823 to 21688).

Please help to get the yellow highlighted result. I wish to autofill column R and S to return the next nearest date that a stock price breaches previous day close.

I hugely appreciate your advise.
Stay safe and healthy!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can help `INDEX`/`MATCH` entered as array formula:

```
=INDEX($A3:$A$9,MATCH(1,--(E2>=$D3:$D$9),0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]